Increase QGIS Server WMTS provided tile size
I am working on a project that requires aerial photos from a WMTS, but the source data I want to use is only available from a WMS. So I figured I could use QGIS Server to provide the WMTS from a QGIS project that includes the WMS aerials in a layer and after some struggles I finally got it working (I am a complete GIS noob).
Now the WMTS only provides tiles in 256x256 pixels which is too low quality for my needs. I tried to find out a way to tell QGIS Server the tile size in pixels it should deliver but the closest I found on here was this:
QGIS Server WMTS custom tile matrix set
This looks like there might be a way to modify the tile size in the bottom two screenshots but I don't know where in the GUI this table is even located.
How can I do this?
